# Terminate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt5

I have an application on pyqt5. And if I click on button time lcd display start to countdown with thread I created. After the countdown finished I cant use the same thread for the same action. How can I terminate that thread and start it again with clicking button

```
class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):   
   def __init__(self):      
     super(window,self).__init__()
     self.button1=QPushButton(self)
     self.lcd=QLCDNumber(self)
     self.tbutton1=threading.Thread(target=self.timing)
   def initUI(self):
       self.lcd.setVisible(False)
       self.button1.clicked.connect(self.timing)
   def timing(self):
      self.tbutton1.start()
      self.lcd.setVisible(True)
        timing=self.spin.value()
        for i in range(timing,-1,-1):
           time.sleep(1)
           if(i<10):
              self.lcd.display("00:0{}".format(i))
           else:
              self.lcd.display("00:{}".format(i))
        self.lcd.setVisible(False)
  if __name__=='__main__':       
     app=QApplication(sys.argv)
     win=window()
     sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: You need to show us some more code. For instance, it looks like both the button click handler and the thread action are the same function, which doesn't sound right.

Comment: at last line of timing function I want to kill thread and if I click it again thread start again and do what is needed

Comment: Please just show us your current code instead of a syntactically incorrect snippet like that.

Comment: so whole code is this it is the same that guys are doind for that reason I assumed that it is not necessary to write all

Comment: While you are on QT i really suggest use also QThread instead of Python threading module.

Comment: actually I cant update MainWindow component from QThread class.They should be 2 seperated class, right?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import threading


class window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):   
    def __init__(self):      
        super(window,self).__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

        self.button1 = QPushButton("Start to countdown", self)
        self.lcd     = QLCDNumber(self)
        self.spin    = QSpinBox(self)

        grid  = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        grid.addWidget(self.lcd)
        grid.addWidget(self.spin)
        grid.addWidget(self.button1)

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
#        self.lcd.setVisible(False)
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.timing)

    def timing(self):
        self.tbutton1 = threading.Thread(target=self.timingThread)
        self.tbutton1.start()
#        self.lcd.setVisible(True)

    def timingThread(self):        
        timing=self.spin.value()
        for i in range(timing, -1, -1):
#            time.sleep(1)
            QtCore.QThread.msleep(1000)
            if(i<10):
                self.lcd.display("00:0{}".format(i))
            else:
                self.lcd.display("00:{}".format(i))
#        self.lcd.setVisible(False)


if __name__=='__main__':       
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: was the problem time.sleep() ? and do you know how thread is being terminated in code?

Comment: You say in another comment: *Widget, including windows, are not thread safe and should only be created/updated in the main thread* but in your code: `self.lcd.display("00:0{}".format(i))` you update the GUI(`self.lcd`) from another thread(`timingThread`), do not you think it's contradictory?